# How do I create multiple jQuery-UI dialog forms and have each one submit unique data?

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I have created a jQuery-UI form to add a note to specific areas of a website.  The form gets submitted to a PHP script for processing.

Each area of the site is defined by an area and a uniqueId.

The modal form works for a single form on the page (i.e. where I only have 1 area and 1 unique Id displayed at any time).  How do I modify the code so that I can re-use as much as possible and cater for multiple areas / uniqueId's on the same page?

One solution I have found is to use PHP to create a separate set of JavaScript methods and a separate div for each area.  This seems like the long way around.

The code is available as a JSFiddle here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgebers/b047hfr6/)

The HTML

```
<h1>Scratch Pad</h1>
<button id="create-note">Add Note</button>
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Note">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Note</label>
      <textarea name="note" id="note" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      </textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="uniqueId" value="1" />
      <input type="hidden" name="area" value="aircraft" />
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript

```
 $(function() {
  var dialog, form;
  function addNote() {
    farea = $('#area').val();
    fnote = $("#note").val();
    funiqueId = $('#uniqueId').val();
    // Post the data
    $.post("api/addnote.php", {
        area: farea,
        uniqueId: funiqueId,
        note: fnote
      },
      function() {
        window.location.reload(true);
        dialog.dialog("close");
      });

  }
  dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Create a note": addNote,
      Cancel: function() {
        dialog.dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      form[0].reset();
    }
  });
  form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addNote();
  });
  $('button[id^="create-note"]').button().on("click", function() {
    dialog.dialog("open");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a conceptual one.  I don't need to create a new form for each button, I just need to set the hidden attributes when the button is clicked.

Full solution: 
HTML

```
<h1>Scratch Pad</h1>
<button id="create-note-1" >Add Note</button>
<button id="create-note-2" >Add another note</button>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Note">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Note</label>
      <textarea name="note" id="note" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      </textarea>
      <input type="hidden" id="uniqueId" name="uniqueId"  />
      <input type="hidden" id="area" name="area" />
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  var dialog, form;
  function addNote() {
    farea = $('#area').val();
    fnote = $("#note").val();
    funiqueId = $('#uniqueId').val();
    // Post the data
    $.post("api/addnote.php", {
        area: farea,
        uniqueId: funiqueId,
        note: fnote
      },
      function() {
        window.location.reload(true);
        dialog.dialog("close");
      });
  }

  dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Create a note": addNote,
      Cancel: function() {
        dialog.dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      form[0].reset();
    }
  });

  form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addNote();
  });
});
```

And the small repeatable snippet for each button:

```
$(function() {
  $("#create-note-1").button().on("click", function() {
    $("#uniqueId").val('1');
    $("#area").val("aircraft");
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
  });
  $("#create-note-2").button().on("click", function() {
    $("#uniqueId").val('8');
    $("#area").val("pilot");
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
  });
});
```